# Android configuration changed

Tags: android, configuration, rotation

I'm interested to know which methods are overridden, when an Android device is rotated (i.e. when configuration changes)?

`onSaveInstanceState(...)`, `onConfigurationChanged(...)`, `onRestoreInstanceState(...)` - something similar to this?

It will be also interesting for me to listen about the whole process connected with changing a configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you rotate the device your Activity will re-create and all the variables will be re-initialized. So, in that case if you want to some values to remain same on Rotation also you can store their state using the `onSaveInstanceState()` and you can restore in `onCreate()` again by checking Bundle is not null.

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
            // get the restore value from the Bundle
        }
```

Where as `onConfigurationChanged()` will be called when you rotate the Device(*Note that this will only be called if you have selected configurations you would like to handle with the `configChanges` attribute in your manifest*). From the parameter you will get the new device configuration.

If you don't want your Activity to get re-created on rotation of Device then you have to add this line to your activity tag in the `AndroidManifest` file.

```
android:ConfigChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: I have a problem with this. I have two layouts: one for landscape and one for portrait. I have a text view. And  I want NOT to lose the typed text on rotation. To this moment I used onConfigurationChanged, there is basically the same staff as in onCreate. The problem is that in onConfigurationChanged I don't have a Bundle and I can't save/retrieve the typed text. When I use onSaveInstanceState() AND onConfigurationChanged(), the first one does not give any effect. I don't know how to solve this issue....

Comment: you retrieve the Bundle values in onCreate() and use it further.

Comment: I understood my mistake, I didn't have to use configChanges. I needed just to override onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState. There I can save/retreive my text view, layout configuration handling is done automatically, so I don't need to do anything else. onConfigurationChanged was overriding everything and I don't need so complicated logic.

Comment: Please be careful with what/how you save. A quote from the developer docs: "you should never pass an object that is tied to the Activity, such as a Drawable, an Adapter, a View or any other object that's associated with a Context. If you do, it will leak all the views and resources of the original activity instance. (Leaking resources means that your application maintains a hold on them and they cannot be garbage-collected, so lots of memory can be lost.)" See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html for more info

Answer (score 6):

According to the android developer reference you have to use:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

For more information see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

You could be interested in seeing: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Here you can find all configuration listener you can listen.

Remember to put them in the android manifest:

```
<activity 
   android:configChanges=["orientation"]
   . . .
</activity>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for "Handling Runtime Changes" link. I'm currently using onConfigurationChanged.

Comment: This answer helped me .. but the part about updating manifest with some form of `android:configChanges` .. I missed that because it was towards the bottom and I'm on a modest screen size.  Not a huge deal .. but might be helpful to have that up near the Java code .. I was setting break points in that method, but they didn't get triggered until I realized I needed the manifest update.  Any which way .. thanks for getting me going in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

From android developers...

To retain an Object during a runtime configuration change:

1. Override the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` method to return the Object you would like to retain.
2. When your Activity is created again, call `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` to recover your Object.

**Android calls onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() between onStop() and onDestroy() when it shuts down your Activity due to a configuration change. In your implementation of onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(), you can return any Object that you need in order to efficiently restore your state after the configuration change.**

A scenario in which this can be valuable is if your application loads a lot of data from the web. If the user changes the orientation of the device and the Activity restarts, your application must re-fetch the data, which could be slow. What you can do instead is implement `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to return an object carrying your data and then retrieve the data when your Activity starts again with `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`.

Look at here for more info [Retaining an Object During a Configuration Change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) you can also find example over their..

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

**Go to Manifest and add**:
*android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"*

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                    />
```

**In Main Activity**: Copy and Paste this code:

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    }
```

All Done -